# In MySQL how to pass a list of integers to a prepared statement in a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement, argument-passing

MySQL 5.0

```
CREATE TABLE `locationcodes` (
  `id` int,
  `customer` varchar(100),
  `locationcode` varchar(50),
  `parentid` int
);

insert into locationcodes values (1, 'Test, Inc.', 'California', NULL);
insert into locationcodes values (2, 'Test, Inc.', 'Los Angeles', 1);
insert into locationcodes values (3, 'Test, Inc.', 'San Francisco', 1);
insert into locationcodes values (4, 'Test, Inc.', 'Sacramento', 1);
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test (_location VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN

SET @location = _location;

SET @select='
  SELECT id, locationcode
  FROM locationcodes  
  WHERE customer="Test, Inc."
  AND id in (?)
  ';

PREPARE stmt FROM @select;
EXECUTE stmt USING @location;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Call procedure:

```
call test('2, 3')
```

Result:

```
2, Los Angeles
```

The result is just one row, but I would like two rows.  The challenge is the prepared statement sees the argument is a varchar, and accordingly puts quotes around the value.  I would prefer no quotes so that I can build a IN statement, how can that be done?  Ideally MySQL would have a list of ints datatype so I would not have to use a varchar, but that does not exist.

I am required to keep the prepared statement to prevent sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's not possible to use a prepared statement with IN() and bind one single value.

For some reason MySQL's API replaces IN() with = (equal) when there is just one single value to bind in the corresponding comparison.

I run some tests with our procedure, that's I got.

With your original procedure that's what MySQL generates (test is my default database):

```
((`test`.`locationcodes`.`customer` = 'Test, Inc.') and 
(`test`.`locationcodes`.`id` = '2,3'))
```

On this case the field id is integer and MySQL converts '2,3' to 2 in the comparison, that's why it returns Los Angeles, '3,2' would return 'San Francisco' obviously.

Just to make sure this was nothing related to the field type (id being a integer), I tried to compare the value with locationcode (varchar), the result is the same.

I changed your procedure to bind two values instead of one.

```
...
SET @select='
  SELECT id, locationcode
  FROM locationcodes  
  WHERE customer="Test, Inc."
  AND id in (?,?)
  ';

PREPARE stmt FROM @select;
EXECUTE stmt USING @location,@location2;
...
```

In this case is creates the statement properly.

```
((`test`.`locationcodes`.`customer` = 'Test, Inc.') and 
(`test`.`locationcodes`.`id` in ('2','3')))
```

That being said, I can tell you'll have to use another approach to accomplish that with a prepared statement.

**After my tests I found this bug report**: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16564

According to Valeriy, create a temporary table with the values and use JOIN. It should work.